# Short story about a boy who lives with his hard-working father, with a mother who had left them

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

A short story I think I read in the early 2010s: It's about a boy whose mother left him following a falling out with his father, so now the new status quo was the father coming home after a long day of work, buying fish and chips. Then one day, the father returns with a smile on his face as he reveals that he had bought a new car. It was quite run down, but they still take it out for a spin, just for fun. The car breaks down and at the mechanic, the dad says something like "maybe next time/another time, son".